# Whats the difference between 127.0.0.1 and ::1

Tags: macos, apache, localhost, hosts, apache-config

For couple day I was fighting to set up apache installed from Homebrew on OSX 10.10 . For some reason everything was working but not the local domains that I was trying to setup via hosts file. No matter what I was doing only http://localhost was available trough browser. And then I've changed one thing.

Originally in /etc/hosts I was putting this line to set local domain:

```
127.0.0.1  imac.dev
```

And that did not work, but then I changed it to:

```
::1  imac.dev
```

which is how localhost was set up in hosts files and it works!

Can anyone explain me why?

Comment: I kind of got it. ::1 is IPv6 address of localhost and 127.0.0.1 is IPv4 address of localhost but why, in my configuration, IPv4 is not working? When I am pingin imac.dev I am getting 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.066 ms even if only ::1 is set up in hosts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is an IPv4 address and the other signifies and IPv6 local address.

Loopback address for ipv4

```
 127.0.0.1  imac.dev
```

Loopback local address for ipv6

```
::1  imac.dev
```

In most current OSes IPv6 if enabled, takes precedence over ipv4 so that might be the reason you were having that issue. Similarly I, had to use IPv6 IP address in my DNS record for SPF because GMail was looking for that too. So whether we like it or not, it's being favored and will replace IPv4 eventually.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost

Comment: ~6 months ago I was doing the same set up on very similar machine with OSX 10.10 but upgraded from 10.8. Is it possible that in OSX 10.8 IPv6 was disabled and OSX 10.10 inherited that setting after update from older version?

Comment: Maybe, I'm not familiar with OSX since I don't really use MAC but I know newer versions are enabled by default. http://www.hpc.mil/index.php/2013-08-29-16-03-23/networking-overview/2013-10-03-17-24-38/ipv6-knowledge-base-ip-transport/enabling-ipv6-in-mac-os-x